# How can I send a message to all players in-game?

Tags: league-of-legends

In League of Legends how do you send a message to all, for example, to say 'Good Game' and the rest

Comment: Another cool tip is to type /r message to respond to someone who messaged from outside your game.

Comment: @danixd - Cool! Since Riot added in-game private messaging I've always wondered how to whisper back without typing the whole name out.

Comment: Sadly, there seems to be a short delay after "/r " (including space) before the last name comes up, meaning if i type "/r message" too fast, i wind up NOT whispering the intended recipient...make sure the name comes up in the chat box, before typing your message!

Answer (score 9):

Just type:
/all *your message here* or *Shift + Enter* to type your message on all chat

If you want more information on Hotkeys and other commands check:
[LOL Hotkeys and other commands](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=8459)

Answer (score 2):

While <kbd>Enter</kbd> brings up team chat, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> brings up all chat.

Conveniently, this is the same way it was in Warcraft III, where the DotA / MOBA model first reached such widespread fame.